# Chrome open address in tab

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create a simple adult filter to get my feet wet in Chrome extension building.

Basically, I have a block list and a redirect list, everything works great and the correct parts fire when the user enters one of block list's domains, and now i want to redirect to google when that happens, so I used this code (that I got after searching Google) :

```
       if (blocked) {
          up = new Object();
          up.url = chrome.extension.getURL("http://www.google.com");
      chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, up);
```

but that seems to be code only to open files locally.
How do I open the URL instead?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `"http://www.google.com"` is not an extension resource, just use:

```
up.url = "http://www.google.com";
```

Comment: Ah! Thank you very much sir! This was driving me crazy looking for an answer. Its quite hard getting relevant results searching with "chrome extension blah blah".

Comment: Not a problem. And of course, the Chrome API docs are a good source of info: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/api_index.html

Comment: I did check there, but have not got the hang of how to actually "use" it. I wish there was a youtube vid explaining how to use the damn api... I have this same problem with the Android dev API.